# XPathで属性名を指定して属性値を取得する方法が知りたい

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping, xpath

プログラミング初心者です。PythonでWebスクレイピングをしたいと考えています。
その際、XPathで属性名を指定して属性値を取得したいのですが、やり方がはっきりと
わかりません。

具体的に申しますと、

```
<a title="1" href="https://hogehoge.co.jp/">
```

というタグがあったとして、「title」という属性名に対する「1」という属性値を
取得したいと考えています。

どのようにすればよいでしょうか？
なにとぞご教示のほど、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

なお、環境はPython3.6.4でJupyterNotebookを使用しています。
ブラウザはGoogleChromeです。

Answer (score 1):

XPath での指定方法は、

```
'//a/@title'
```

です。
lxmlでの例です。

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
el = fromstring('<a title="1" href="https://hogehoge.co.jp/">')
el.xpath('//a/@title')
['1']
```